# bind arraylist to dropdown menu list c#

Tags: c#

I want to bind my `arraylist` to dropdown menu list. Here is my code.
I'm a beginner to C#. Please help.

```
if (selectinidialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    selectinibtn.Text = selectinidialog.FileName;
    IniFile inifile = new IniFile(selectinidialog.FileName);

    string[] sectorelist = inifile.GetSectionNames();
    var sectorno = new List<string[]>;
    sectorno.Sort();
    selectsectorbtn.DataSource = sectorno;
    selectsectorbtn.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting the data you want:

```
string[] sectorelist = inifile.GetSectionNames();
```

But then you don't do anything with that data.  (You never use the `sectorelist` variable again.)  Instead, you create a new empty list and bind to that:

```
var sectorno = new List<string[]>;
sectorno.Sort();
selectsectorbtn.DataSource = sectorno;
selectsectorbtn.DataBind();
```

Are you just looking to bind to the data you first got from `inifile`?:

```
string[] sectorelist = inifile.GetSectionNames();
selectsectorbtn.DataSource = sectorelist;
selectsectorbtn.DataBind();
```

It's worth a try.  Though it's not entirely clear what you're specifically trying to do because you're working with two very different types here.  You fetch a `string[]` but then you try to bind to a `List<string[]>`.  If you need to bind to the latter for some reason then you'd need to translate the former to that somehow (based on whatever logic you'd use to define that translation).  But if that was just a typo or other simple mistake, then it sounds like you can just bind to the data and don't need that `List<string[]>` at all.

Comment: I want to use this sectorlist to my dropdown menu named selectsectorbtn.

Comment: @N.Jadav: And is this not working as expected in some way?  "I want to do something" doesn't really describe any kind of problem which prevents you from doing it.

Comment: I just want to bind this array of sectorelist to my dropdown menu list.

Comment: @N.Jadav: If the suggestion made in this answer isn't working in some way, you're going to have to explain the error.  I can't see your screen from here.  If you just want to keep repeating the same thing over and over until somebody writes your entire project for you, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest but dont take my answer for the best 1 that you rather not directly bind the list with an array.
rather loop through it and add one item at a time or use the AddRange() functionality in the right conditions.
Example :

```
    if (selectinidialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //lets say this is the dropdown list
        DropDownList list = new DropDownList();

        selectinibtn.Text = selectinidialog.FileName;
        IniFile inifile = new IniFile(selectinidialog.FileName);

        string[] sectorelist = inifile.GetSectionNames();

        list.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in sectorelist)
        {
            //make sure this if statement always runs
            if(true == true && false == false && true != false && false != true && 1 == 1)
            {
                list.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = item });
            }

        }

    }
```